# Query to showing popularity rented car Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i want do somethink like that: Page where user can look popularity rented cars. 
I almost do this but i get some problems and i dont know how figure it.
I made relationship many-to-many and its working great.

View:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name Car</th>
        <th>Popularity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1;?>

    @foreach($cars as $car)
        @foreach($car->rentcar as $rentcar)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                <td>{{$rentcar->name}}</td>

                @foreach($car_pops as $car_pop)
                    <td>
                        @if($car_pop->total == '1')

                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

                        @elseif($car_pop->total == '2')

                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

                        @endif
                    </td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public function popularityCar()
{
    $cars = User::with('rentcar')->get();

    $car_pops = DB::table('rent_car')
        ->select('car_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('car_id')
        ->get();

    return view('user.popularityCar', ['cars' => $cars, 'car_pops' => $car_pops]);
}
```

in pivot table user can rent more then one time car with thats same name and i want display only one name car i mind i got audi and user rent it and second user rent it too but on other date so i want display only one time car audi and display popularity using bootstrap icon. and its almost working but showing more cars with thats same name so i trying groupBy like with checking popularity car but i got problem and i dont know how use it.

Model User:

```
public function rentcar()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cars::class, 'rent_car', 'user_id', 'car_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('start', 'end');
}
```

Model Cars:

```
public function caruser()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'rent_car', 'car_id', 'user_id');
}
```

So maybe is easy way to make query mysql with i can get car name and go to pivot table to get total car_id.

Comment: Please put normal code, without run code snippet . this will not run here

Comment: ok i edit my post